# Python2 - printing an object's default attributes

Tags: python, class

I'm new to OOP, but I'm trying to look at an object's vars. Other Stack-O answers have suggested using `object.__dict__` or `vars(object)`. So I went into the Python shell to try a quick example, but I noticed neither of these answers prints the object's default attributes, only newly-assigned attributes, e.g.:

```
>>> class Classy():
...     inty = 3
...     stringy = "whatevs"
... 
>>> object = Classy()
>>> object.inty
3
>>> object.__dict__
{}
>>> vars(object)
{}
>>> object.inty = 27
>>> vars(object)
{'inty': 27}
>>> object.__dict__
{'inty': 27}
```

Why are the variables present in one sense but not another? Is it because I didn't explicitly initialize them or something?

Comment: These variables are assigned to the class, not an object, so try `Classy.__dict__` instead (contains some more internal attributes)

Comment: But when I type `>>>object.inty`, it returns `3`. Doesn't that mean the variable is assigned to the object as well?

Comment: @mblakesley no that's not what that means. Furthermore, those aren't really "default values", they are *class attributes*.

Comment: @mblakesley check out [this](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/#object-attribute-lookup) explanation of how attribute access work in Python. Note again, you don't have instance attributes here, but class attributes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Came back to this and I think I get it now. So my original confusion was because `object.attr` will reference the object attribute if it exists, otherwise it'll reference the class attribute. That's probably convenient but it's confusing at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important understanding that in Python everything is an object (including functions, and a `class` declaration itself)

When you do this:

```
class Classy():
    inty = 3
    stringy = "whatevs"
```

You're assigning `inty` and `stringy` to the `Class`, not to the instances. Check this:

```
class Classy():
    inty = 3
    stringy = "whatevs"

print(Classy.__dict__)
```

Wait... A `class` with a `__dict__`? Yeah, because `Classy` is also an instance (of type `classobj`, since you're using [old style classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass), which you shouldn't really do, by the way... You should inherit from `object`, which gives you access to more *goodies*)

```
>>> print(type(Classy))
<type 'classobj'>
```

Now, if you created an *instance* of classy, and put an `inty` value to it, you would have:

```
class Classy():
    inty = 3
    stringy = "whatevs"

    def __init__(self):
        self.inty = 5

classy = Classy()
print("__dict__ of instance: %s" % classy.__dict__)
print("__dict__ of Class: %s" % classy.__class__.__dict__)
```

Which outputs

```
__dict__ of instance: {'inty': 5}
__dict__ of Class: {'__module__': '__main__', 'inty': 3, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x1080de410>, 'stringy': 'whatevs'}
```

See the `inty` being 5 in the `__dict__` of the instance but still being 3 in the `__dict__` of the class? It's because now you have two `inty`: One attached to `classy`, an instance of the class `Classy` and another one attached to the class `Classy` itself (which is, in turn, an instance of `classobj`)

If you did

```
classy = Classy()
print(classy.inty)
print(classy.stringy)
```

You'd see:

```
5
whatevs
```

Why? Because when you try to get `inty` on the instance, Python will look for it in the `__dict__` of the *instance* first. If it doesn't find it, it will go to the `__dict__` of the class. That is what's happening on `classy.stringy`. Is it in the `classy` **instance**? Nopes. Is it in the `Classy` **class**? Yep! Aight, return that one... And that's the one you see.

Also, I mentioned that the Classy class is an object, right? And as such, you can assign it to something else like this:

```
What = Classy  # No parenthesis
foo = What()
print(foo.inty)
```

And you'll see the `5` that was "attached" in `Classy.__init__` because when you did `What = Classy`, you're assigning the `class Classy` to a variable named `What`, and when you do `foo=What()` you're actually running the constructor of `Classy` (remember: `What` and `Classy` are the same thing)

Another thing Python allows (and that I personally don't like because then it makes code very difficult to follow) is attaching attributes to instances "on-the-fly":

```
classy = Classy()
try:
    print(classy.other_thing)
except AttributeError:
    print("Oh, dang!! No 'other_thing' attribute!!")
classy.other_thing = "hello"
print(classy.other_thing)
```

Will output

```
Oh, dang!! No 'other_thing' attribute!!
hello
```

Oh, and did I say that functions are objects? Yeah, they are... and as such, you can also assign attributes to them (also, something that makes code really, really confusing) but you could do it...

```
def foo_function():
    return None # Very dummy thing we're doing here
print("dict of foo_function=%s" % foo_function.__dict__)
foo_function.horrible_thing_to_do = "http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/"
print("Horrible thing? %s" % foo_function.horrible_thing_to_do)
```

Outputs:

```
dict of foo_function={}
Horrible thing? http://www.nooooooooooooooo.com/
```

Comment: Sure! I hope you have fun playing with these things. And wait until you learn about Metaclasses !!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python
**:D**  It's really fun!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vars` or `__dict__` with the class name, not instance:

Option 1:

```
class Classy:
   inty = 3
   stringy = "whatevs"

final_vals = {a:b for a, b in vars(Classy).items() if a not in ['__doc__', '__module__']}
```

Output:

```
{'inty': 3, 'stringy': 'whatevs'}
```

Option 2:

```
final_vals = {a:b for a, b in Classy.__dict__.items() if a not in ['__doc__', '__module__']}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the `.__dict__` and `vars` methods aren't working as you expected is because you haven't defined a constructor for your class with python's `self` reference. The following will do what you're looking for:

```
class Classy():
    def __init__(self):
        self.inty = 3
        self.stringy = 'whatevs'

object = Classy()
object.__dict__
vars(object)
```

Outputs:

```
{'inty': 3, 'stringy': 'whatevs'}
{'inty': 3, 'stringy': 'whatevs'}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Okay, well that's what I figured, but my original scenario still doesn't make sense to me. How can `object.inty` return a value while `object.__dict__` doesn't?