# Associating attribute to function

Tags: python

I have the following method,

```
def MySampleMethod():
    return "Sample method called"
```

I tried the following code,

```
MySampleMethod.variablename = "Some data"
print MySampleMethod.variablename
```

The code executed without error and printed "`Some data`".

How is it possible to assign a variable to a function and how it works ?

Comment: Because everything in python is an object, including functions. **BUT** keep in mind that the fact you can do something, doesn't mean you *should* do it... Allow me to make a bit of [Spam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031685/289011) of my own answer... **:-D**

Comment: Thank you so much BorrajaX. It was really informative.